# DAO is null inside atmosphere's ManagedService?

Tags: java, singleton, dropwizard, atmosphere

Hi i am working with `dropwizard` and atmosphere's managed service to create rest apis and socket too. Whenever i am trying to access `MyDAO` inside `@ManagedService` its always null.

```
@Singleton
@ManagedService(path = "/chat/{rooms: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*}")
public class ChatRoom{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GameService.class);

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    private final static String CHAR= "/chat/";

    private MyDAO myDAO;

 @Ready(encoders = {InitialMessageEncoder.class})
    @DeliverTo(DeliverTo.DELIVER_TO.ALL)
    public InitialMessage onReady(final AtmosphereResource r) {
        logger.info("type:{}", myDAO);
    }
}
```

MyDAO is just mongoDB methods for doing data manipulations in db.For accessing even used inject not working and i am unable to use constructor too ?

Comment: you don't seem to instantiate or autowire it.

Comment: Where is `MyDao` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: can't autowire inside drpwizard right ? @Stultuske

Comment: there is a package which contains all DAO @M.Prokhorov

Comment: @hrudaykumarreddy, that doesn't answer my question. Why is it supposed to be not a null? Is it assigned in constructor? Has a setter for it? Marked as injectable resource?

Comment: @hrudaykumarreddy your class has no access to it. You declare it, but you still need to instantiate it

Comment: inside constructor you mean right  ? @Stultuske

Comment: I tried inject its not working if i use it inside constructor  i'm getting this error

[2020-01-09 11:14:48,051] org.atmosphere.annotation.ManagedServiceProcessor:
! java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.game.resources.websocket.ChatRoom.<init>()
! at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
! ... 70 common frames omitted @M.Prokhorov

Comment: I tried inject its not working if i use it inside constructor  i'm getting this error

[2020-01-09 11:14:48,051] org.atmosphere.annotation.ManagedServiceProcessor:
! java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.game.resources.websocket.ChatRoom.<init>()
! at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
! ... 70 common frames omitted @Stultuske

Comment: Seriously, we don't know your code. Do you need to call the constructor within the constructor? no. You need to call it where you need to call it.

Comment: @Stultuske i am very new to this can you elaborate a bit

Comment: if you are new to this, you should first learn the basics.